# Cannot find symbol on my array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm getting some errors with a method that I am making but I don't know what it means or how to fix it.

The error says:
DataSet.java:99: error: cannot find symbol
      int size = this.medianArray.length;

```
public double median()
{  
  double[] medianArray = getData();
  Arrays.sort(medianArray);
  int size = this.medianArray.length;
  int one = 1;
  int two = 2;

  double median = 0.0;
  if (size % 2 == 0) {
  median = this.medianArray[size / two] + this.medianArray[(size / two) + one];
  median = median / two;
  } 
  else 
  {
  // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, (6), 7, 8, 9, 10 , 11 
  median = this.medianArray[((size - one) / two) + one];
  }
  return median;

}
```

Oh the getData method just creates a copy of the array:

```
public double[] getData()
{


  double[] DataCopy = new double[size()];

    for (int k = 0; k < size(); k++)
        DataCopy[k] = this.data[k];

    return DataCopy;

  }
```

Comment: Is there a `medianArray` field in your class? What's the complete and exact error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
int size = this.medianArray.length;
```

`medianArray` is local to the `median` function, but you are referencing it with `this`:

Within an instance method or a constructor, `this` is a reference to the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being called. You can refer to any member field of the current object from within an instance method or a constructor by using `this`.

Remove `this` and you should be good to go. Please take a look in this official tutorial page: [**Using the `this` Keyword**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

Comment: Thank you, I kept on using this all over my program because that is what my professor said to do. So I should only use it when referring to a variable outside a specific method. If the variable is already declared in a method I should not bother.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword "this", means that medianArray is an attribute of your class. In you case, it's a local variable inside your function, you can simply do

```
medianArray.length
```

Answer (score 0):

Concentrate on this in the `median()` method:

```
double[] medianArray = getData();
Arrays.sort(medianArray);
int size = this.medianArray.length;
```

You create `medianArray` as a **local** variable. Later you try to reference it as a class member variable.

This is not possible, change the last line to: `int size = medianArray.length;`.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely is the array `medianArray` is not a filed of your class and probably you want to use `medianArray` returned by `getData()`. So just remove the `this` before it in the statement in line 99.